# Why can't I apply value to entire pandas column after subsetting my data frame by two conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a data frame with three columns, representing Year, Name, and Year_2

I'd like to change the value of the Year_2 column based on Year and Name, like such:

`(df[(df['Year']==1980) & (df['Name'].str.contains("John"))])['Year_2']=2010`

I thought this would be the same thing as typing

`df[Year_2] = 2010`,

but clearly I'm missing something super basic, because looking at my dF once more shows that none of these changes have been applied... Would appreciate someone putting me out of my misery here, because I can't quite understand where I'm messing up the syntax.

Comment: You mean `df.loc[(df[(df['Year']==1980) & (df['Name'].str.contains("John")),'Year_2'] = 2010`

Comment: You can try `df.loc[(df['Year']==1980) & (df['Name'].str.contains("John")),'Year_2'] = 2010`

Comment: @EdChum, I ended up getting a nasty looking Key Error: `KeyError: '[None None None None None None None None None None None None None None None\n None None None None None None None None None None None None None None None\n None None None None None None None None None None None None None None] not in index' — bummer;

@jezrael, that worked, thanks!!!

Comment: There was a typo in my suggestion due to the number of braces and square brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[(df['Year']==1980) & (df['Name'].str.contains("John")),'Year_2'] = 2010
```